# Git SSL Root CA

Tags: ssl, git

I would like to configure my local Git client installation to use the preloaded root certificates in Microsoft Windows 7+ or the Git ca-bundle.crt.

Is there a way to configure Git to use the Windows Certificates that are already available(i.e. Comodo, DigiCert)?

What Root CA Certs are already available in the ca-bundle.crt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the configuration options `http.sslCAInfo` and `http.sslCAPath` you can direct git to use the CA information you wish.
You can use the command `openssl x509 -text -in ca-bundle.crt` to see its content decoded.